# Java Scanner try catch multiple data types

Tags: java, try-catch

First of all thanks for everything you, guys are doing here on stack overflow. It helped me a lot many times!
My problem today is a little issue with try/catch instruction using along with Scanner. Take a look at my method for adding products to a recipe:

```
public static void addProducts(List<Product> product, Scanner sc)
{
    if (run == true)
    {
        Maths calc = new Maths();
        //Some instructions in Polish, not needed here :)
        while (true)
        {
            String name = null;
            double quantity = 0;
            double pricePerUnit = 0;
            try
            {
                name = sc.nextLine();
                if (name.equals("0") || name.equals("exit"))
                {
                    Logic.run = false;
                    break;
                }
                quantity = sc.nextDouble();
                sc.nextLine();
                pricePerUnit = sc.nextDouble();
                sc.nextLine();

                product.add(new Product(product.size() + 1, name, calc.round(quantity, 2), calc.round(pricePerUnit, 2)));
                System.out.println("Product added: " + "\n" + product.get(product.size() - 1));
            } catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Please repeat your last input.");
            }
        }
        double num = 0;
        for (Product p : product)
        {
            num += p.getPrice();
        }
        Maths.setTotalPrice(num);
        System.out.println("Total: " + num);

    } else
    {
        System.out.println("You have already added products to the recipe!");
    }
}
```

As you can see im reading String, double and double in the try/catch instruction. For example when adding "potatoes" to the recipe I accidentaly write "horse" where quantity should be I get a product named "horse" instead of "potatoes". Is that clear? I have a yellow duck right here but its easier to explain in my native language than it is in English :)
If there is anything unclear I will do my best to explaing, thanks!

Comment: You can use `if (run)` instead of `if (run == true)`.

Comment: Just confirming: is your input 3 lines for each item? name, quantity, price?

Comment: Are you getting errors? What isn't working?

Comment: @Bohemian - yes, thats correct. Product has its name, quantity and price.

Comment: @sebenalem - its working fine, but Im loosing input if I make a mistake when inputing wrong data type, read the post again please :)

Comment: @dorukayhan - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
quantity = sc.nextDouble();
sc.nextLine();
```

you're throwing away any extra input, without acknowledgement. If you want to restrict user to only enter a number and nothing else on a line, use:

```
quantity = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()); // maybe add .trim()
```

If you leave your code unchanged, remember that when `InputMismatchException` is thrown, the `Scanner` is still sitting on (at beginning of) the bad input, so you need to discard that:

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error! Please repeat your last input.");
    sc.nextLine(); // discard bad input
}
```

Of course, your code will loop around and prompt for all 3 inputs, so error message is a bit misleading.

Comment: I had to change catch(InputMismatchException e) to catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) when using Double.parseDouble, but my problem still occures. When I catch the error when entering quantity I loose what I have given as Name. I understand the only way to do this is tell the user to repeat whole product. Is that right? Or should I brake one try/catch into three for every data I enter?

Comment: No, you don't have to start over. Instead of a single loop, going back to the beginning, create 3 loops, one for each value. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself): A nice helper method might be good, to reduce repetitive code.